# How does the LinkedList inside the Map change?

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list

In the following code,I create a map that accepts `LinkedList` as its value. Using a particular key I get the `LinkedList`, modify it and print the values to check if it was modified.

As the values get printed, I see it modified. But I don't expect the values inside the LinkedList to change until I do,

```
map.put(for_the_same_key,modified_list) // so that old key gets replaced by this
```

Why does the `LinkedList` inside the map change when I modified a new `LinkedList`.

```
import java.util.*;

class MapTester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<Integer,LinkedList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<String>>();
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        list.add("Suhail");
        list.add("Gupta");
        list.add("CSE");

        map.put(1,list);

        LinkedList<String> newList = map.get(1);
        newList.add(2,"Khayal");
        newList.remove(3);

        LinkedList<String> newListAg = map.get(1);
        for(String s : newListAg) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }       
    }
}
```

The output :

```
Suhail
Gupta
Khayal // I EXPECTED 'CSE' HERE
```

Comment: What is the purpose of line: newList.remove(3); ?

Comment: @arjacsoh to remove the element with index number 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map stores a reference to a list. It does not care about the object the reference points to, if it is mutable it may change its state. Invoking `put` is necessary if you want to change the **map** state itself - to change the reference associated with the key, e.g. associate an entirely different, new `List` with the key.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a new `LinkedList`:

```
LinkedList<String> newList = map.get(1);
newList.add(2,"Khayal");
newList.remove(3);
```

It returns the existing `LinkedList` from the `Map` which you are then modifying. So everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are just referencing the same list and **NOT** creating a new list below.

```
LinkedList<String> newList = map.get(1);
```

thats why eventhough you are modifying `newList`, `list` also gets modify.

Try changing it as below,

```
LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>(map.get(1));
```